# Submitted form input arrays are duplicating with Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a very strange thing that seems to be happening.

I have a form with an input array (for the purposes of this there is only one though) which when it gets submitted and I dd the result I can see the value gets duplicated.

Here's my code...

This is Controller

```
class FormController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->has('grade_id')) {
            dd($request->all());
        }

        return view('form');
    }
}
```

This is View

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="get" action="{!! route('form-test') !!}">
    <input name="grade_id[]" value="1" type="checkbox" id="grade_id" class="grade_id">Outstanding
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">Search</button>
</form>
```

Result

```
array:1 
  "grade_id" => array:2
    0 => "1"
    1 => "1"
  ]
]
```

What's happening?

If you want to check it out for yourself I have created a repo for it. https://github.com/bencarter78/form-test

Weirdly someone from the larachat slack room tried out the repo and it worked fine for them but when I do it I get it duplicated. Why might we be getting 2 different results for something like this?

Comment: Pull in the repo to a different folder and see if you have the same issue

Comment: Have you tried using `POST` instead of `GET`?

Comment: @Alfa Yes I've tried `POST` and it works fine, its when I `GET` the request data that the issue occurs.

Comment: Guess it because of the browser behavior when building URL query from the form.